# Two version of the same code not giving the same result

Tags: ruby, multithreading, timer

I am trying to implement a simple timeout class that handles timeouts of different requests.

Here is the first version:

```
class MyTimer
  def handleTimeout mHash, k
    while mHash[k] > 0 do
        mHash[k] -=1
        sleep 1
        puts "#{k} : #{mHash[k]}"
    end
  end
end

MAX = 3

timeout = Hash.new
timeout[1] = 41
timeout[2] = 5
timeout[3] = 14

t1 = MyTimer.new 
t2 = MyTimer.new 
t3 = MyTimer.new 

first = Thread.new do
    t1.handleTimeout(timeout,1)
end

second = Thread.new do 
    t2.handleTimeout(timeout,2)
end

third = Thread.new do 
    t3.handleTimeout(timeout,3)
end

first.join
second.join
third.join
```

This seems to work fine. All the timeouts work independently of each other.
[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzOO4.png)

The second version of the code however produces different results:

```
class MyTimer
  def handleTimeout mHash, k
    while mHash[k] > 0 do
        mHash[k] -=1
        sleep 1
        puts "#{k} : #{mHash[k]}"
    end
  end
end

MAX = 3

timeout = Hash.new
timers = Array.new(MAX+1)
threads = Array.new(MAX+1)


for i in 0..MAX do
  timeout[i] = rand(40)
  # To see timeout value
  puts "#{i} : #{timeout[i]}"
end

sleep 1

for i in 0..MAX do
  timers[i] = MyTimer.new
  threads[i] = Thread.new do
    timers[i].handleTimeout( timeout, i)
  end
end


for i in 0..MAX do
  threads[i].join
end
```

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e79LS.png)

Why is this happening?

How can I implement this functionality using arrays?

Is there a better way to implement the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop in which you are creating threads by using `Thread.new`, the variable `i` is shared between `main` thread (where threads are getting created) and in the threads created.  So, the value of `i` seen by `handleTimeout` is not consistent and you get different results.

You can validate this by adding a debug statement in your method:

```
 #...
 def handleTimeout mHash, k
    puts "Handle timeout called for #{mHash} and #{k}"
    #...
 end
 #...
```

To fix the issue, you need to use code like below. Here parameters are passed to `Thread.new` and subsequently accessed using block variables.

```
for i in 0..MAX do
  timers[i] = MyTimer.new
  threads[i] = Thread.new(timeout, i) do |a, b|
    timers[i].handleTimeout(a, b)
  end
end
```

More on this issue is described in [When do you need to pass arguments to `Thread.new`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745840/when-do-you-need-to-pass-arguments-to-thread-new) and this [article](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/ruby-threads-gotcha-with-local-vars-and-shared-state/).

Comment: I'll use something like this to handle timeouts for requests to a server. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @B.Nabi What kind of requests are these? HTTP?

Comment: Yes HTTP requests.